Angular 18: set InjectionToken after APP_INITIALIZER provider
In angular 18, I need to set API URL after the app initialisation(because for obvious reason, fetching of URL from a json file). However it is not setting. In fact InjectionToken has set before APP_INITIALIZER even though it was added later in providers array in app.config.ts
Reference: https://angular.dev/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER?tab=usage-notes
Here is theStackblitz
expecting to set API_URL_TOKEN to url value and use it further for all the API calls. store in localStorage and assign.
private apiUrl = inject(API_URL_TOKEN);
loginUser(data: { username: string; password: string }) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/auth`, data).pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        if (res.success) {
          this.addToken(res.data);
        }
      })
    );
  }

Here is what I tried
main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)

app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([authInterceptor, errorInterceptor])),
    provideAppInitializer(),
    provideApiUrl(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideCharts(withDefaultRegisterables()),
  ],
};


app-initializer.ts
const CONFIG_URL = '/config.json';

function appInitializer(http: HttpClient, storageService: StorageService) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const config = await firstValueFrom(http.get<{apiUrl: string}>(CONFIG_URL));
      storageService.apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
      console.log('Config loaded successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
}

export function provideAppInitializer(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializer,
    deps: [HttpClient, StorageService],
    multi: true,
  };
}

app-url-token.ts
export const API_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('API_URL_TOKEN');

function apiUrlFactory(storageService: StorageService): string {
  const apiUrl = storageService.apiUrl;
  if (apiUrl) {
    return apiUrl;
  }
  throw new Error('API URL not found in configuration');
}

export function provideApiUrl(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: API_URL_TOKEN,
    useFactory: apiUrlFactory,
    deps: [StorageService],
    multi: false,
  };
}

/* another way */
export const API_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('API_URL_TOKEN');

export function provideApiUrl(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: API_URL_TOKEN,
    useValue: (storageService: StorageService) => storageService.getApiUrl,
    deps: [StorageService],
  };
}


storage.service.ts
import { inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

const LOCAL_STORAGE = new InjectionToken<Storage>('Browser Storage', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => localStorage,
});

const API_URL = 'apiUrl';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StorageService {
  private readonly storage = inject<Storage>(LOCAL_STORAGE);

  get(key: string) {
    return this.storage.getItem(key);
  }
  set(key: string, value: string): void {
    this.storage.setItem(key, value);
  }

  remove(key: string): void {
    return this.storage.removeItem(key);
  }

  clear() {
    return this.storage.clear();
  }

  get apiUrl(): string | null {
    return this.storage.getItem(API_URL) || null;
  }

  set apiUrl(url: string) {
    this.storage.setItem(API_URL, url);
  }
}


On start up

on refresh

In second case its clear that, it is before the initialiser
About config.json


The below github issue helped me understand what went wrong.
HTTP_INTERCEPTOR does not wait for APP_INITIALLIZER
Since your interceptor uses HttpClient, this in turn calls the interceptor hence you are getting this issue. The solution to this problem is to use HttpBackend whose requests are not intercepted by the interceptor, this will solve your problem. The input should be passed as HttpRequest
function appInitializer(http: HttpBackend, storageService: StorageService) {
  return () => {
    return http.handle(new HttpRequest('GET', CONFIG_URL)).pipe(
      map((config: any) => {
        storageService.apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
        console.log('Config loaded successfully');
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
        throw error;
      })
    );
  };
}

export function provideAppInitializer(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializer,
    deps: [HttpBackend, StorageService],
    multi: true,
  };
}


Place your config.json in an assets folder,to fetch the data. Then configure this in the angular.json's assets folder, so that it will be discoverable. As seen in the stackblitz.
   ...
   },
      "options": {
        "assets": ["src/assets"],
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "browser": "src/main.ts",
        ...

You can get rid of the async await and do this with pure rxjs. we can use map to assign the values to storage and use catchError to catch any exceptions.
function appInitializer(http: HttpClient, storageService: StorageService) {
  return () => {
    return http.get<XiConfig>(CONFIG_URL).pipe(
      map((config: any) => {
        storageService.apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
        console.log('Config loaded successfully');
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
        throw error;
      })
    );
  };
}

One more Thing is you need to import the app config to bootstrap application.
bootstrapApplication(App, appConfig);

Then finally access this on the component.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(@Inject(API_URL_TOKEN) private urlToken: string) {
    console.log(urlToken);
  }
}

Full Code:
Main.ts
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { API_URL_TOKEN } from './app/app-url-token';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      standalone: true,
      template: `
        <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
          Learn more about Angular
        </a>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      name = 'Angular';

      constructor(@Inject(API_URL_TOKEN) private urlToken: string) {
        console.log(urlToken);
      }
    }

bootstrapApplication(App, appConfig);

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import {
  provideHttpClient,
  withFetch,
  withInterceptors,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAppInitializer } from './app-initializer';
import { provideApiUrl } from './app-url-token';
//import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
//import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
//import { provideCharts, withDefaultRegisterables } from 'ng2-charts';
//import { routes } from './app.routes';
//import { authInterceptor } from './interceptors/auth.interceptor';
//import { errorInterceptor } from './interceptors/error.interceptor';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([])),
    provideAppInitializer(),
    provideApiUrl(),
    //provideRouter(routes),
    //provideAnimationsAsync(),
    //provideCharts(withDefaultRegisterables()),
  ],
};

app.url.token
import { InjectionToken, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

export const API_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('API_URL_TOKEN');

function apiUrlFactory(storageService: StorageService): any {
  console.log(storageService.apiUrl);
  const apiUrl = storageService.apiUrl;
  if (apiUrl) {
    console.log('set apiUrl');
    return apiUrl;
  }
  throw new Error('API URL not found in configuration');
}

/*

export const API_URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('API_URL_TOKEN');

export function provideApiUrl(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: API_URL_TOKEN,
    useValue: (storageService: StorageService) => storageService.getApiUrl,
    deps: [StorageService],
  };
}


*/

export function provideApiUrl(): Provider {
  return {
    provide: API_URL_TOKEN,
    useFactory: apiUrlFactory,
    deps: [StorageService],
    multi: false,
  };
}

App initializer:
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs';

interface XiConfig {
  apiUrl: string;
}

const CONFIG_URL = '/assets/config.json';

    function appInitializer(http: HttpBackend, storageService: StorageService) {
      return () => {
        return http.handle(new HttpRequest('GET', CONFIG_URL)).pipe(
          map((config: any) => {
            storageService.apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
            console.log('Config loaded successfully');
          }),
          catchError((error: any) => {
            console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
            throw error;
          })
        );
      };
    }

    export function provideAppInitializer(): Provider {
      return {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: appInitializer,
        deps: [HttpBackend, StorageService],
        multi: true,
      };
    }

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the answer, it works in stackblitz. however not in the app . I have added the screenshot of the error with your solution. please check.

@skdonthi missed a step, updated now, please check!

Do you mean config.json? if yes, then it was already in path and fetching the correct data. in angular 18 onwards it is in public folder. in angular.json its is like this. "assets": [ {"glob": "**/*", "input": "public" } ]. see the screenshots attached, on startup and on refresh. you will see the problem. thanks in advance

@skdonthi Try doing console.log and checking if the response is received, maybe the path is incorrect for fetching the JSON

see the screenshot, About Config.json. it is correctly fetching. problem occurs in startup

@skdonthi share the github repo or replicate on stackblitz please, need it to validate what's going on

Figured that provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor, errorInterceptor])),is causing the problem. not sure why.
https://angular.dev/guide/http/interceptors#configuring-interceptors

Damn, its because of the interceptor is injected with a service. that service has API_URL_TOKEN injector.

@skdonthi Thanks I understand now, updated my answer with the solution for this issue.
