Moving to Angular 17 - InjectionToken not getting received in APP_INITIALIZER and <app-root> not rendered
The original code was for a working MEAN stack project in Angular 12 and Node 16. Needed to move this to Angular 17.
What was done:
For moving this project to angular 17.3.8, on a laptop Angular 17 and Node 20 was installed.
A new project was generated using ng new ...
All the project files from old project was copied into respective folders.
The errors thrown by Angular CLI were resolved.
These errors were were primarily due to strict typing and the requirement of resolvers and auth guard to be of function type instead of class type.
The only other difference was the absence of environment folder.
I have replaced environment variable by passing it as run time variable using a json file in assets folder and
getting the values in an injection token using appInitializer provider.
However, this injection token is not getting received at right time. And <app-root> is not getting rendered.
After running npm start, and visiting localhost:4200
nothing happens with a blank screen, No errors appear in console.
When back button is clicked on browser and then clicked forward again only the h1 tag in index.html gets rendered and the errors appear in console - see attached.
saw this and updated my method of getting config json data from assets folder: Angular 18: set InjectionToken after APP_INITIALIZER provider
what did I miss?
Below are the code snippets.
index.html
  ...
    <body>
        <h1>TITLE</h1>            /// << THIS GETS RENDERED
        <app-root></app-root>     /// << DOESNOT GET RENEDERED
    </body>
     ...

main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

// if (appConfig.production) {
//   enableProdMode();
// }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

assets/appconfig.json
{
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:3100/api",
  "myCompany": "xyz",
  "smallScreenWidth": 450,
  "production": false
}

app.module
   ... imports ...
     

const MY_APP_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiUrl: '',
  myCompany: '',
  smallScreenWidth: 450,
  production: false,
};
// function initializeAppConfig(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<AppConfig> {
//   console.log('running initializeAppConfig')
//   return () =>
//     httpClient.get<AppConfig>('assets/appconfig.json').pipe(
//       tap((config) =>
//         Object.assign(MY_APP_CONFIG, {...config})
//       )
//     );
// }

/// changed the above to below after seeing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811664/angular-18-set-injectiontoken-after-app-initializer-provider

function initializeAppConfig(http: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    return http.get<AppConfig>('/assets/appconfig.json').pipe(
      map((config: any) => {
        Object.assign(MY_APP_CONFIG, {...config})
        console.log('MY_APP_CONFIG assigned: ', MY_APP_CONFIG);
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
        throw error;
      })
    );
  };
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AlertConfirmDialogComponent, AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent, DeleteConfirmDialogComponent,
    ErrorDialogComponent,
    HeaderComponent, MyNotificationsComponent,
    RegisterClientPrimaryComponent, RegisterPrimaryComponent, RefreshComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PdfJsViewerModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeAppConfig, multi: true, deps: [HttpClient] },
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: MY_APP_CONFIG },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitializer, multi: true, deps: [AccountService] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    WINDOW_PROVIDERS, LocationService, provideAnimationsAsync()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


app.component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  appConfig = inject(APP_CONFIG);
  smallScreenWidth: number = this.appConfig.smallScreenWidth;
  baseUrl: string = this.appConfig.apiUrl;

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService
  ){
   }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('in app-component ngOnInit')
    this.accountSub = this.accountService.account.subscribe(x => {
      .....


second APP_INITIALIZER - triggers the below service method
import { APP_CONFIG } from '../app.configToken';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountService {
  appConfig = inject(APP_CONFIG);
  smallScreenWidth: number = this.appConfig.smallScreenWidth;
  baseUrl: string = this.appConfig.apiUrl;

  reqUrl: string = this.baseUrl + '/auth'

  refreshToken() {
    console.log('acService checking refr tkn @ ', this.baseUrl)
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.reqUrl}/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(map(account => {
            .....

expected use of appConfigToken
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_CONFIG } from '../app.configToken';

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading = false;
  appConfig = inject(APP_CONFIG);
  smallScreenWidth: number = this.appConfig.smallScreenWidth;
  baseUrl: string = this.appConfig.apiUrl;
    



UPDATE:
Updated initializeAppConfig in app module as per Naren's reply. The line return firstValueFrom(obs$) gives a new error. Ref the console screenshot.
While bootstrapping app module, the network tab in console shows that header component is pending and points to line 28 of component template.
header.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading = false;
  appConfig = inject(APP_CONFIG);
  smallScreenWidth: number = this.appConfig.smallScreenWidth;
  baseUrl: string = this.appConfig.apiUrl;

  account!: Account | null;

  constructor(
    public accountService: AccountService
    ) {
    this.accountService.account.subscribe(x => {
      this.isLoading = false
      this.account = x;
      if(this.account){
        if(this.account.accCtl && this.account.accCtl.userIsClient) {
          if(this.account.diy && (this.account.accCtl.planCob || this.account.accCtl.planPmla || this.account.accCtl.planKyc)) this.showDiyLinks = true;
  
        } else {
          this.showDiyLinks = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }

header.component.html
<div class="app-toolbar">
    <mat-icon  class="menu-icon" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" *ngIf="account" >menu</mat-icon>
    <span class="header-title">{{hdrTitle}}</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    ......
</div>
<div class="progress-container" *ngIf="isLoading">
  <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="accent"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">   /// line 28
  <div *ngIf="account && account.accCtl">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="" *ngIf="account.accCtl.showOAM">
      <mat-icon>speed</mat-icon>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
    </button>
    .....
</mat-menu>

screenshots of console and network tabs



I would not create a new project, but use the existing one and use ng update instead.

I am not sure why observables do not work when they are returned by the factory function.
The solution to the problem, is to return a promise instead of an observable, this causes the APP_INITIALIZER to execute in order.
I am using rxjs firstValueFrom to convert the observable to a promise.
Also instead of map use tap, prefer map when you want to tranform the response from the observable, since no transformation done, we can use a tap instead.
function initializeAppConfig(http: HttpClient, accountService: AccountService) {
  return () => {
    const obs$ = http.get<AppConfig>('/assets/appconfig.json').pipe( // <- changed here!
      tap((config: any) => { // <- changed here!
        Object.assign(MY_APP_CONFIG, {...config})
        console.log('MY_APP_CONFIG assigned: ', MY_APP_CONFIG);
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error('Error loading configuration:', error);
        throw error;
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.accountService.refreshToken())
    )
    return firstValueFrom(obs$);
  };
}


Still the error. Two problems: 1. initializeAppConfig function takes time to execute. So by the time injectionToken is initialized from the file in assets folder,  second appInitializer gets executed and throws an error.  I resolved this error temporarily by assigning the correct values to the token in app module itself. But the second issue still persists. 2. There is some issue with bootstrapping of AppModule which generates Promise.then (anonymous) error on this line in main.ts - platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));

@hemant get rid of the second app initializer, use only one, its giving you timing issues. You can use switchMap of rxjs to switch to the second app initializer code, after the first has executed, updated my answer!

Updated initializeAppConfig in app module. The line return firstValueFrom(obs$) gives a new error. While bootstrapping app module, the network tab in console shows that header component is pending and points to line 28 of component template. See the update in the post. I would like to try the older method of using environments folder, BUT this needs to be resolved. Is Zone having any conflicts with Angular 17?

@hemant Then try without the firstValueFrom and just observable sequence, it should work. If not please share a simple stackblitz where the timing issue happens for me to check, also hope you are using only one APP_INITIALIZER

The problem was somewhere else. A line in Auth Guard caused it to run in a loop. Therefore, the App Module never got bootstrapped fully and so the  was not rendered. Now it is resolved. Your refactored code for initializeAppConfig was useful though.
